# MouseEnter Event for ag-grid manipulation

Tags: angular, mouseover, ag-grid

I need to manipulate row Style and also want to add some HTML elements on mouse Enter.

I have found **mouseEnter: Mouse has entered the row.** event for RowNode; added below line code.

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode((node: RowNode) => node.addEventListener('mouseEnter',function(){ console.log('mouseover event!')}))
```

I want to add html element on row who generate mouseover event.
Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: append the html element to the element that represents RowNode.

Comment: Do you want to add particular style or more content on hovered row?

Comment: I want to add some icons and click event handler on that icons (Angular 6)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create you own cell renderer to achieve this. Having your own cell renderer will allow you to have full control over your cell so you can capture the event and do whatever you need to do on it.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Hope this helps